# iOS: Decrypt method crash on devices with the A5 chip

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt a file, but this method fails on devices with A5 chip. (signal SIGABRT) New devices work fine.

Why is this happening?

```
- (void) decryptFile{

unsigned char bookhashChar[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
NSData *stringBytes = [self.bookhash dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; /* or some other encoding */
if (CC_SHA1([stringBytes bytes], (CC_LONG)[self.bookhash length], bookhashChar)) {
    /* SHA-1 hash has been calculated and stored in 'digest'. */
}
unsigned char idBookChar[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSData *stringBytesForID = [self.book_id dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; /* or some other encoding */
if (CC_SHA1([stringBytesForID bytes], (CC_LONG)[self.book_id length], idBookChar)) {
    /* SHA-1 hash has been calculated and stored in 'digest'. */
}

char resultKey[kCCKeySizeAES128+1];
for (int i = 0; i< kCCKeySizeAES128+1; i++) {
    resultKey[i] = (Byte)(bookhashChar[i] ^ idBookChar[i]);
}


char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));

char ivPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
char ivv[17] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x03, 0x00, 0x06, 0x03, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };

//[iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self.downloadedData length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;

CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,resultKey, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      ivv /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self.downloadedData bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesDecrypted);

if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    self.downloadedData = [[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted] copy];
}
```

Comment: There are https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor and https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor. Could you check if the issue persists with these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is using `kCCKeySizeAES128+1` for the returned size of `CCSHA1`. Don't mix the value types, AES with SHA1.

The digest size of `CCSHA1` is CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH, 20 bytes.
The size of `kCCKeySizeAES128` is 16 bytes.

The buffer for `CCSHA1` is to small.

Sooner or later there will be an overwrite of 3 bytes and incorrect operation  (possible a crash) will occur.

You may only need `kCCKeySizeAES128` bytes but the buffer must be large enough for `CCSHA1` and then use the bytes needed.